# what is poorly formatted http response (malformed http response)?

Tags: java, http, heroku

I am running java application on heroku. I get this exception at any time (randomly). with any random file, sometimes with static files (like js, css) and some time with dynamic files (as jsp)

I want to know what this actually mean, and how can I resolve this problem.

Thanks (in advance)

Comment: [Read, don't ask](https://www.google.com/search?q=malformed+http+response+heroku&oq=malformed+http+response+heroku&aqs=chrome..69i57.6271j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: I read all those things, but still I dont get the problem properly, so I asked here. If you understood then can you please explain it to me!
Thanks !!!